# Evaporation of a gravitationally-bound spherical cloud of a warm ideal gas in a vacuum

Tags: newtonian-gravity, temperature, astrophysics, ideal-gas, stellar-evolution

It seems that for any gravitationally bound system with a very large number of atoms/particles, there will always be some particles that manage to achieve escape speed and ultimately leave the cloud.  The cloud that remains will be a little smaller and, presumably, a little cooler(?). I assume the cloud will continue to evaporate indefinitely but at a slower and slower rate - never quite stopping. 
I am interested in the dynamics of this process. The simplest configuration might be a vacuum containing a cloud with perfect spherical symmetry and zero net rotation. We can assume an ideal gas with a mean-free path that is small compared to the size of the cloud.  Perhaps also assume that the gas is in *quasi-equilibrium*, meaning that the radial density, pressure, temperature, and gravitational field profiles mutually stabilize on very much shorter timescales than the time taken for the cloud to evaporate. 
I have two questions, one related to the long time evolution and the other to the profiles within the cloud:

1. How does this process evolve in the long term?  Are we ultimately left with a small dense core of atoms that are not necessarily cool but are in a very deep potential well?  Does the evaporation proceed roughly logarithmically?  Are three parameters completely sufficient to describe the cloud: e.g. total mass,  atomic mass, temperature?
2. In the *quasi-equilibrium* state, what do the radial profiles of density, temperature, pressure, and gravity  look like and how are they interlinked?  If the cloud is in some short-term thermal equilibrium, does this mean that the average of the sum of the kinetic energy plus potential energy is constant? ( i.e. $(3/2)kT(r) - GmM(r)/r$ is constant?  - here $m$ would be the atomic mass and $M(r)$ the mass of the cloud inside radius, $r$)

Thanks in advance for any guidance or references.

Comment: Search for simulations of globular clusters. Such systems are not stable, only quasi-stable (obeying virial theorem). Eventually they lose much of the particles and the rest gets very dense at the center. For gas/dust, condensation/chemical reactions may change the results.

Comment: @ Ján Lalinský Thanks, that's a valuable sugggestion. It looks like there's quite a lot of literature on the topic.  The Wikipedia article suggests that the distribution of stellar masses and the presence of binaries is important in the evolution.  I can't help thinking that for the simple ideal gas model I have in mind, that there must be some closed-form expression or at least some relatively simple numerical result.  I'll keep looking.